# django PostgreSQL arrayfield store a 3 dimension array

Tags: django, postgresql, arraylist

This is the list I want to store in my database :

```
[30, 9.45, 
[3.4499999999999993, 1.0500000000000007], 
[10.625, 12.875], 
[14.075, 11.825], 
[9.0, 15.0], 
[12.904858299595142, 15.637651821862349], 
[15.0, 18.0], 
[1.0, 1.0], 
[6.0, 10.5], 
[10.5, 6.0], 
[0.0, 0.0], 
[[3, 6], [3, 6, 6]], 
[[6.0, 1.5], [10.5, 6.0, 4.5]], 
[27.0, 94.5], 
[110.1141194331984, 106.83476720647775]]
```

my models.py :

```
D240_TOTAL = ArrayField(
            ArrayField(
                models.FloatField(max_length=10, blank=True),
                blank=True, null=True,
            ),
            blank=True, null=True,
        )
```

but  am getting the error :

Field 'D240_TOTAL' expected a number but got [3, 6].

because my field is 2-d array but i am giving him a 3d array

my edited field :

```
M_BC_TOTAL = ArrayField(
                ArrayField(

                    ArrayField(
                        models.FloatField(max_length=10, blank=True),
                        blank=True, null=True,
                    ), blank=True,null=True),
                blank=True, null=True,
        )
```

but  am getting this error : can't adapt type 'numpy.int32'

Comment: change your code so that you store a 2D array, or add another `ArrayField`, or use a `JSONField` to store any list

Comment: @Louis-JustinTallot  i tried to add another  Arrayfield but i am getting this error : can't adapt type 'numpy.int32'   you can take a look at my edited question

Comment: the problem here is that your array is heterogeneous : `[1, [2, 3] , [[4, 5], [6, 7]]]` so Django cannot pass a number as an array. You should use `JSONField` (cf my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change you Model to use a [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) instead. This will allow you to store any list :

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

D240_TOTAL = JSONField()
```

See also [here](https://pganalyze.com/blog/postgres-jsonb-django-python) for an how-to of `JSONField`.

Comment: don't forget to run migrations after you changed your model !